# How to make Perlin Noise/color gradient generation in Python similar to the noise in a C++ tutorial?

Tags: python, c++, gradient, noise, perlin-noise

I'm currently trying to use noise to generate random fantasy maps in Python. I found [a tutorial](http://www.jgallant.com/procedurally-generating-wrapping-world-maps-in-unity-csharp-part-3/#heatmap) online that really helped me. Unfortunately, it's in C++, so I've had to toy around with my code to get it as close as possible. Obviously, it's impossible to get everything to be one-to-one. For example, he uses accidental noise, and I use perlin. I still want to give it a try.

While I'm overall happy with how it's turning out, there's a major issue bugging me.

In both my and the tutorial's programs, a number between 0 and 1 (in my case, the numbers get smaller from the center of the y-axis and then are changed to be between 0 and 1) determines what color each part of the gradient will be. In the tutorial's picture, red is the majority color in the center, but the other colors are more or less equal to each other. Mine is close to that, but some colors are definitely larger, with the dark blue (all numbers less than 0.05) being just a small strip. I've tried changing the size of the gradient, but that made the dark blue overtake all the other colors. I'm stumped. Is the issue that the tutorial's gradient originally goes from red at the center to blue while mine goes from white to black? Is it the size of my gradient? Should I just change the numbers I used from the tutorial?

[Tutorial's Gradient Heat Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L4X1.png)

[My Gradient Heat Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RLyc.png)

**My Code**

```
import numpy as np
import math
import noise
from PIL import Image

shape = (500,500)
width = shape[0]
height = shape[1]
scale       = 100 # Number that determines at what distance to view the noisemap
octaves     = 6 # the number of levels of detail you want you perlin noise to have
persistence = 0.5 # number that determines how much detail is added or removed at each octave (adjusts frequency)
lacunarity  = 2.0 # number that determines how much each octave contributes to the overall shape (adjusts amplitude)

def add_color(arr):
    color_world = np.zeros(arr.shape+(3,))
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            if arr[x][y] < .20:
                color_world[x][y] = [70,130,180]
            elif arr[x][y] < .40:
                color_world[x][y] = [100,149,237]
            elif arr[x][y] < .50:
                color_world[x][y] = [154,205,50]
            elif arr[x][y] < .70:
                color_world[x][y] = [0,128,0]
            elif arr[x][y] < .80:
                color_world[x][y] = [192,192,192]
            elif arr[x][y] < 1.0:
                color_world[x][y] = [255,255,255]
    return color_world

world = np.zeros(shape)
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        world[x][y] = noise.pnoise2(x/scale, 
                                    y/scale, 
                                    octaves     = octaves, 
                                    persistence = persistence, 
                                    lacunarity  = lacunarity, 
                                    repeatx     = 500, 
                                    repeaty     = 500, 
                                    base        = 0)
heat_noise = np.zeros(shape)
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        heat_noise[x][y] = noise.pnoise2(x/scale, 
                                    y/scale, 
                                    octaves     = 4, 
                                    persistence = persistence, 
                                    lacunarity  = lacunarity, 
                                    repeatx     = 500, 
                                    repeaty     = 500, 
                                    base        = 0)
# get world between 0 and 1         
max_grad = np.max(world)
min_grad = np.min(world)
world = (world-min_grad)/(max_grad-min_grad)

# get heat_noise between 0 and 1         
max_grad = np.max(heat_noise)
min_grad = np.min(heat_noise)
heat_noise = (heat_noise-min_grad)/(max_grad-min_grad)


# Show noise
##im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(world*255),"L")
##im.show()

# make world height colorful
color_world = add_color(world)

# Create colored world height map image to view
im = Image.fromarray(color_world.astype("uint8"), "RGB")
im.show()

# create gradient starting from center going up and down
center_y = width/2
heat_grad = np.zeros_like(world)
for y in range(world.shape[0]):
    for x in range(world.shape[1]):
        disty = abs(y - center_y)
        dist =(disty*disty)
        heat_grad[y][x] = dist

# get gradient between -1 and 1
max_grad = np.max(heat_grad)
heat_grad = heat_grad / max_grad
heat_grad -= 0.5
heat_grad *= 2.0
heat_grad = -heat_grad

# shrink gradient down
##for x in range(width):
##    for y in range(height):
##        if heat_grad[x][y] > 0:
##            heat_grad[x][y] *= 20

# Multiply world height by gradient
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        heat_grad[x][y] = (heat_grad[x][y] * heat_noise[x][y])

# get gradient between 0 and 1
max_grad = np.max(heat_grad)
min_grad = np.min(heat_grad)
heat_grad = (heat_grad - min_grad)/(max_grad - min_grad)

# show gradient in image
im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(heat_grad*255),"L")
im.show()

# add color to heat_grad
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        if heat_grad[x][y] < 0.05:
            color_world[x][y] = [0,0,255] 
        elif heat_grad[x][y] < 0.20:
            color_world[x][y] = [100,100,255] 
        elif heat_grad[x][y] < 0.40:
            color_world[x][y] = [0,255,0] 
        elif heat_grad[x][y] < 0.60:
            color_world[x][y] = [255,246,0]
        elif heat_grad[x][y] < 0.80:
            color_world[x][y] = [255,140,0]
        else:
            color_world[x][y] = [255,0,0]

#create heat map based on noise
im = Image.fromarray(color_world.astype("uint8"),"RGB")
im.save("./imagetest.png")
im.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're asking several distinct questions, which makes the overall post a bit broad by Stack Overflow's [question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Try to pare down this post, and if necessary you can ask multiple questions for each of the related problems you're having. Monolithic questions can scare away potential answer-ers, but split it up into more manageable chunks and you'll get solutions more quickly :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I got rid of the other two questions. I hope it fits the guidelines better now.

Comment: Yep, looks good! The only other potential thing I would do is try to pare down your code block to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The less "stuff" people have to scroll through, the better. I don't know enough to tell if your code is "minimal enough", and it's probably fine as it is now, but I thought I'd throw it out there just in case